# Loading data to SAP HANA

Tags: hana

I am having my CSV file in `/usr/sap/DB1/HDB/work` and also having my control file which has the following code

```
IMPORT DATA INTO TABLE target_schema."table_name" 
FROM '/usr/sap/DB1/HDB/work/table_name.csv'
RECORD DELIMITED BY '\n' 
FIELDS DELIMITED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
ERROR LOG ' table_name.err' ​
```

Afterwards when I execute the following query in SQL

```
IMPORT FROM '/usr/sap/DB1/HDB/work/table_name.ctl';
```

I am getting error

> [258]: insufficient privilege: Not authorized.

But I am logged in as SYSTEM user. Could anyone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three things that need to be done :

1. The SYSTEM user must have the "IMPORT" privileges.
2. Alter the Index Server service to read the CTL and CSV file from the location.
3. The Tables in which data you are inserting should have the Insert Privileges.

Comment: Missing import Privilages was the main problem.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The user *hdbadm* is usually not a HANA database user but a Linux user on the HANA server. Are you sure you are using this for the HANA login? Have you tried using the *SYSTEM* user?

Either way, check the user privileges in SAP HANA Studio: He should have the system privileges *IMPORT* and *INSERT*.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion hdbadm is indeed a Linux user,but I logged into HANA as SYSTEM user only and executed the query.The above error occurs for security reasons.So how to grant **import system privilege and write access** to target schema?

Answer (score 0):

In the navigation pane of Hana studio, under the your System name click security. expand security then go to Users and click on your username
.In the Right side of the navigation pane you will find option to alter privileges.